# Adaptive background after rotation/deskew in Imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

After I rotate or deskew an image with Imagemagick there's a white background in the corners, where the rotation took place. Example:

```
convert image.png -rotate 10 out.png
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMRhl.jpg

Is there a way I could somehow fill up those white corners with some texture or at least a color that blends in with the image? Cropping is not an option.

I've found this great solution for simple rotation:

```
convert image.png -virtual-pixel Edge +distort SRT 10 out.png
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUIr8.jpg

But unfortunately it doesn't work with the `-deskew` command...

So, does anyone know how to fill up those corners in a similar way for the `-deskew` (and `-rotate`) command? The point is to mask the fact the image was rotated as best as possible.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any white corners...

Comment: Only because the browser window is white :) http://imgur.com/SqVM3

Comment: Could you render it on a black background, please? :)

Comment: I changed the wording, put the pic on a black background, and added another image. Hope I'm making sense now.

Comment: You either didn't specify your problem correctly or you forgot to accept the working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question, but I'm still hoping for a better solution.

You can set the `-background` color, which works with rotate and deskew.

Here's a solution that uses the average image color:

```
convert image.png -background `convert image.png -resize 1x1 txt:- | tail -1 | cut -b 30-50` -rotate 10 out.png
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u6CH.jpg

And a better solution that takes some border pixels:

```
convert image.png -background `convert image.png -resize 100x1! \( +clone -crop 1x1+0+0 \) +append -crop 2x1+99+0 -resize 1x1 txt:- | tail -1 | cut -b 30-50` -rotate 10 out.png
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwki6.jpg

There's some bash scripting (inside the backticks), so these solutions are unix only.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
convert image.png -background transparent -rotate 10 out.png
```

Comment: The corners can't get more invisible than this. Why wasn't this accepted yet ?

Comment: I'd like to fill that space with something as best as possible, not just make it transparent. The second link is an example, but it doesn't work for the -deskew command (and other basic transformations). Sorry, I keep on editing and adding content to the question as I'm learning more...

Comment: What is "as best as possible" ? I would think that maybe you want to inpaint the created background.